# plugin is not calling in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am developing a plugin. But when i am calling the plugin then it says method is undefined

```
;(function($){

    $.dialog = {

        defaults : {
            ...
        } //end of defaults

    }; //end of  $.dialog = {}

    $.fn.extend({

        dialog : function(userConfig) {

            var config = (userConfig) ?$.extend({}, $.dialog.defaults, userConfig) 
                                      : $.dialog.defaults;

            config.selector = "#" + this.attr("id");

            $.dialog.createUI(config);

            return this;

        } //end of function(userConfig)

    }); //end of $.fn.extend({})
    ..
})(jQuery);
```

And i am calling it like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.dialog();

}); //end of $(document).ready(fn)
```

It says **$.dialog is not a function**. what am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use

```
$.extend()
```

instead of

```
$.fn.extend()
```

if you want to call your plugin

```
$.dialog();
```

instead of

```
$('yourselector').dialog();
```

Comment: Thanks. You mean when i want to call on selector then i should use `$.fn.extend()`, but if i want to simply call it then there is no need of **$.fn**.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you want to call the `dialog()` method on an element selection? e.g.

```
$("dialogContainer").dialog();
```

Comment: No i don't want to all it on element selector as you did `$("dialogContainer").dialog();`. I want to call it like `$.dialog();` or `$.dialog({});`.

Comment: Interesting approach. Just means that if you want several dialogs on a page, you have to call $.dialog({ selector: "dialog1" }); $.dialog({ selector: "dialog2" }), etc, instead of just calling $(".dialogs").dialog(); You can't use class names either because your dialog() method forces the use of ID selectors. Incidentally, where you have this.attr("id"), what does this actually point to? Because it isn't an element and therefore won't have an id attribute. I'm not saying it's wrong, just interesting. Any particular reason why you took this approach?

Comment: :) I am writing my first plugin. Yup there is no need of `config.selector = "#" + this.attr("id");` in this case. As this is my first plugin, so obviously i will make mistakes :). Actually i first read someone plugin, in that plugin he used **$.fn**. So that's why i used it:). But at-least i came to know that what is the difference between these two and also you point me one thing that i can use this approach to create multiple dialogs:). Thanks

Comment: I shudder to think what my first plugin must have looked like ;) $.plugin_name has its uses for sure, I tend to reserve it for when stuff needs to be done to the page in general on every load, and use $.fn.plugin_name for when stuff needs to be done to specific elements